# Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a \neq b, \sqrt[n]{\frac{a+b}{2}}>\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+\sqrt[n]{b}}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Do for any natural $n$ and $a\neq b$,
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{a+b}{2}} > \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+\sqrt[n]{b}}{2} ?$$
I proved it for $n=2,3$.
Now is it true  for natural number $n$?

Thank you

Comment: It isn't true for $a=b$. You need an equality sign

Comment: @FShrike  sorry. a is not equal b. i forget to write it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality

Comment: Are $a, b \ge 0$?

Comment: Nitpick: The title is wrong for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The n'th root function $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is a concave function (second derivative is negative for $n\gt1$) and you can therefore use Jensen's inequality which states that for a concave function
$$
\varphi\left(\frac{\sum x_{i}}{n}\right) \geq \frac{\sum \varphi\left(x_{i}\right)}{n}
$$
Which directly gives you the following
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{a+b}{2}} \geq \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+\sqrt[n]{b}}{2}
$$
Furthermore, only when $a=b$ the above holds with equality.